# How to Check existence of User using ADFS api

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, adfs2.0

I have ADFS2.0 claims aware asp.net mvc2 application. In the application there is a administrator functionality to add user to the database in order to control the roles and permission access functionality in the application.

I want to know regarding whether there are any APIs or web services from ADFS default installation to use, in order to check for valid user before adding the user to database.

Can anyone please help me to know more details about the above mentioned question?

Thanks & Regards,
Santosh Kumar Patro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ADFS is a STS (Security Token Service) which essentially handles authentication and authorisation via claims.

It is not an Identity Manager.

Out of the box, no - there is no such functionality.

You need to [extend](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee895356.aspx) ADFS yourself using the AD API's - [Howto: (Almost) Everything In Active Directory via C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18102/Howto-Almost-Everything-In-Active-Directory-via-C).